# How to rename duplicate labels with names such as _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm working on a program that combines multiple assembly files into one for a project. It works in most cases, but I'm stuck on this one.

After combining the assembly files, when I try to compile it, I get these errors:

```
combined.S: Assembler messages:
combined.S:1513: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:5602: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:15379: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:19894: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:23290: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:25446: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:25854: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:26353: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:33720: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:51959: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:60363: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:61420: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:63286: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:72006: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:88682: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:110804: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:112062: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:112853: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:115062: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2' is already defined
combined.S:115619: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2' is already defined
combined.S:116175: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2' is already defined
combined.S:121514: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:123271: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:123911: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:124522: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:126673: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:127356: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:128014: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:128610: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:132812: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
combined.S:134749: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2' is already defined
combined.S:140900: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2' is already defined
combined.S:143234: Error: symbol `_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1' is already defined
```

This makes sense because there are duplicates. If I rename just one of them, the error that corresponds to it goes away. However, when I modify all of their names, I get a ton more errors:

```
combined.S:110368: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
combined.S:110369: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110371: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110372: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
combined.S:110373: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110375: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110376: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
combined.S:110377: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110379: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110380: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
combined.S:110381: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110383: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110384: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
combined.S:110385: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110387: Error: invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections) for `-'
combined.S:110388: Error: invalid operands (.text and .text._ZN5ggBSTI10ggMaterialE17InsertIntoSubtreeERK8ggStringPS0_RP9ggBSTNodeIS0_E sections) for `-'
```

There appears to be this new problem on almost every line. I modified the names by appending the file name of the assembly file they were in to the name of the label before the `.part`. Here is a diff between the first file with the duplicate names, and the second file that has the labels renamed:

```
900,901c900,901
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox2_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox2_s.part.1:
918c918
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox2_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox2_s.part.1
1512,1513c1512,1513
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox3_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox3_s.part.1:
1530c1530
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox3_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggBox3_s.part.1
5601,5602c5601,5602
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBFPixel_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBFPixel_s.part.1:
5619c5619
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBFPixel_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBFPixel_s.part.1
15378,15379c15378,15379
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggDiffuseMaterial_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggDiffuseMaterial_s.part.1:
15396c15396
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggDiffuseMaterial_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggDiffuseMaterial_s.part.1
17334,17335c17334,17335
<   .type   _Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2, @function
< _Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2:
---
>   .type   _Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2, @function
> _Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2:
17608c17608
<   .size   _Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2, .-_Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2
---
>   .size   _Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2, .-_Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2
17879c17879
<   call    _Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2
---
>   call    _Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2
18431c18431
<   jmp _Z13areaUnderLineddd.part.2
---
>   jmp _Z13areaUnderLinedddggEdgeDiscrepancy_s.part.2
19893,19894c19893,19894
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggQuaternion_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggQuaternion_s.part.1:
19911c19911
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggQuaternion_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggQuaternion_s.part.1
23289,23290c23289,23290
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggONB3_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggONB3_s.part.1:
23307c23307
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggONB3_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggONB3_s.part.1
25445,25446c25445,25446
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame2_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame2_s.part.1:
25463c25463
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame2_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame2_s.part.1
25853,25854c25853,25854
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame3_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame3_s.part.1:
25871c25871
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame3_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFrame3_s.part.1
26352,26353c26352,26353
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHMatrix3_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHMatrix3_s.part.1:
26370c26370
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHMatrix3_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHMatrix3_s.part.1
33719,33720c33719,33720
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBE_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBE_s.part.1:
33737c33737
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBE_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggRGBE_s.part.1
51958,51959c51958,51959
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHPoint3_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHPoint3_s.part.1:
51976c51976
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHPoint3_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggHPoint3_s.part.1
60362,60363c60362,60363
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggString_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggString_s.part.1:
60380c60380
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggString_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggString_s.part.1
61141c61141
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggString_s.part.1
61419,61420c61419,61420
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFineSpectrum_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFineSpectrum_s.part.1:
61437c61437
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFineSpectrum_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggFineSpectrum_s.part.1
63285,63286c63285,63286
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggSpectrum_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggSpectrum_s.part.1:
63303c63303
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggSpectrum_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcggSpectrum_s.part.1
65063,65064c65063,65064
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.5, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.5:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.part.5, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.part.5:
65081c65081
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.5, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.5
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.part.5, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.part.5
65083,65084c65083,65084
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16:
65130c65130
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70602c70602
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70621c70621
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70642c70642
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70663c70663
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70673c70673
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70721c70721
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70735c70735
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70857c70857
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70884c70884
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
70892c70892
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71267c71267
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71284c71284
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71294c71294
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71306c71306
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71323c71323
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
71340c71340
<   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.constprop.16
---
>   call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceon_s.constprop.16
72005,72006c72005,72006
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceonImageCalculator_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceonImageCalculator_s.part.1:
72023c72023
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceonImageCalculator_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKceonImageCalculator_s.part.1
88681,88682c88681,88682
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrGrid_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrGrid_s.part.1:
88699c88699
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrGrid_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrGrid_s.part.1
92675,92676c92675,92676
<   .type   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40, @function
< _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40:
---
>   .type   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40, @function
> _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40:
92698c92698
<   .size   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40, .-_ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   .size   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40, .-_ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
92701,92702c92701,92702
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrScene_s.part.2, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrScene_s.part.2:
92719c92719
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrScene_s.part.2, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrScene_s.part.2
97233,97234c97233,97234
<   .type   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46, @function
< _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46:
---
>   .type   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46, @function
> _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46:
97310c97310
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
97644c97644
<   .size   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46, .-_ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46
---
>   .size   _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46, .-_ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46
97724c97724
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
102974c102974
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46
105261c105261
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46
105320c105320
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.constprop.46
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.constprop.46
105581c105581
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
105730c105730
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
105759c105759
<   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_i.part.40
---
>   call    _ZN7mrScene9AddObjectEP9mrSurfaceRK8ggStringS4_imrScene_s.part.40
110803,110804c110803,110804
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrCamera_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrCamera_s.part.1:
110821c110821
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrCamera_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrCamera_s.part.1
112061,112062c112061,112062
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrTriangle_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrTriangle_s.part.1:
112079c112079
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrTriangle_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrTriangle_s.part.1
112852,112853c112852,112853
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrFastTriangle_s.part.1, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrFastTriangle_s.part.1:
112870c112870
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.1
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrFastTriangle_s.part.1, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrFastTriangle_s.part.1
115061,115062c115061,115062
<   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2, @function
< _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2:
---
>   .type   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrXYDisk_s.part.2, @function
> _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrXYDisk_s.part.2:
115079c115079
<   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc.part.2
---
>   .size   _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrXYDisk_s.part.2, .-_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKcmrXYDisk_s.part.2
```

It goes on too. Does anyone have an idea on how I can rename these labels? Let me know if there is any other information you need or something I should try!

Comment: May I ask what exactly are you trying to do by messing with ASM and bits and pieces of the STL...? Plus this should be tagged C++ if you're using the STL since that's obviously not available in C.

Comment: I changed the tag. I wrote a program that combines assembly files together for a research project! I'm working with C and C++ programs from the SPECInt 2000 benchmark. It is working on all of them except this one (eon) because I'm not sure how to rewrite these labels.

Comment: Rather than show us a massive dump of largely duplicated and mostly identical errors it would be a lot more helpful if you told us how you got to those errors and showed a *minimal* yet complete example of that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use a C++ demangler to find out what this does:

http://demangler.com/

Results in:

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*).part.1
```

So, this is the implementation of the << operator. That means you're trying to add the C++ standard library twice in your program. Include it only once instead.

Comment: Hmm ok. Thanks for the tip! I just went through and removed all the duplicate labels by hand. From your comment, I was thinking maybe every assembly file was including the C++ standard library. After doing this, it still gave me all the `invalid operands (.text and *UND* sections)` errors, so maybe that is caused by another problem?

Comment: I don't know. You need to check the original build files for eon to see which libraries are being linked. Suggestion is to first make sure you can link the executable without your custom code, then use the same steps to link it.

Comment: It does link without my custom code. I have another idea of what the other errors could be coming from so I'm planning on testing that. Thanks for your help!